# How to know which module to import to use a class?

Tags: flutter, dart

With flutter/dart, how to quickly know which package / module to import for a class?

For example, looking at the Class `RenderRepaintBoundary`, and its doc page: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary-class.html  , I have no idea how to import it.

The compiler errors would just look like

```
Error: 'RenderRepaintBoundary' isn't a type.
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = ...
```

without pointers regarding missing imports.

Comment: Quote from docs you shared: "To use, import package:flutter/rendering.dart.".

Comment: If you are using an IDE like VS Code or Android Studio, it usually auto imports the package needed for the class, if your editor is not doing so then use an extension, or switch to an IDE, or try updating your IDE and plugins and check your configuration file.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Really? I did a fulltext search for your quote and didn't find it on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top left of the docs, in this case [RenderRepaintBoundary class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary-class.html), there is a hierarchy given like

`Flutter > rendering > RenderRepaintBoundary class`.

From there you can find the package in which a particular class belongs to.

In this case clicking on `rendering` shows the package to import.

> rendering library The Flutter rendering tree.
>
> To use, import package:flutter/rendering.dart.

Comment: Thanks. Totally missed the top-left corner!